# Message queue with read lock

Tags: message-queue, azureservicebus

I'm looking and researching for message queues (MQ) that have read-lock or peek-lock feature. However, I couldn't yet found any options except Azure Service Bus.

Could anyone shares possible alternatives of MQ with similar peek-lock?

Thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Can you provide some other criteria for the queue?  Do you need persistent messages, transactions, partitions, journaling, etc.?

Comment: Could you please clarify what the desired behavior is? "Peek-lock" does not mean anything to me.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage Queues is another alternative on Azure where message can be locked by a reader. Outside of Azure you have variety of MQ options.